# Layer-wise linear combination of two neural network models in Pytorch

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch, neural-network

I have two trained neural network models M1 and M2 in Pytorch.

Both have exactly the same neural network architecture (same # of layers, which we will denote by 'n').
Furthermore, I have a n-dimensional vector 'lambda', where each value 'lambda_i' is in range [0, 1].

What I want to calculate now is the 'layer-wise' linear combination 'M = lambda * M1 + (1 - lambda) * M2'.
Means that the i-th layer in M is calculated as the linear combination of the i-th layer in M1 (using factor 'lambda_n') and the i-th layer in M2 (using factor '1 - lambda_i').
The linear combination shall be done both for 'weight' and 'bias' of the i-th layer.

How can I calculate this in Pytorch ?

Comment: Is that useful? You can reorder the output=input of next layer (applying the inverse permutation to the columns and rows of the weight matrices) between inner layers without changing the network as function. Interpolation will then be quite wild, but the intended result would be a constant interpolation path. So it could be useful to first sort the inner layers so that the distance of the weight matrices is minimal.

Comment: It might be useful. That's what I want to check ...

Comment: And that is what I used it for ... https://zenodo.org/record/8208680